# pip install virtualenv taking forever on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, python, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to setup everything in order to start developing with python and Django on a Windows 7 laptop. I already installed python 2.7.11 from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/python-2.7.11.msi) and installed pip using the get-pip.py script and the instructions from [this website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). Now I'm trying to install virtualenv because I'm also following the heroku's tutorial to get started with python which indicates to do so, so I ran the command "pip install virtualenv" but the command prompt just stays stuck forever showing the typical white dash blinking endlessly.

What can I do? I just want to get past the setup phase and start to actually develop stuff with Django. I was thinking of not using pip at all but then how would I go about installing packages? Should I start from scratch using a virtual machine with Ubuntu instead?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you're behind a corporate proxy, but defining http_proxy and https_proxy with the following values helped for me (example on windows):

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy.company.com:8000/
set https_proxy=https://proxy.company.com:8000/
c:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe my-virtual-env
```

Comment: To be more specific, the issue is that virtualenv tries to go out and look for packages on PyPi even if they're already available locally, and if PyPi isn't accessible it will sit there and wait for the timeout for every package. If you know you already have the packages locally, you can add `--never-download` to prevent this behavior.